# I have a bunch of great photos that I would like to sell online, in the Android Marketplace, and Itunes for iphone and ipad. Suggestions?

Tags: iphone, android, video, photo-gallery

I have decent programming skills and could create an Android app and an iPhone app, but the application is so simple, I was wondering if anyone already knew of an app to already do this.  I have thousands of images and videos that I would like to sell.  I could either sell them in "bundles" where each app would have 100 pictures and 5 videos or so.. but I'd prefer to have the person purchase "galleries" so they would pay for each set of 100 pictures / videos Separately.

I have the skills to create an RSS feed, use my own payment processing system (although I don't think Android likes free apps to have a separate way of collecting money from the publisher).

Suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The in-app products / billing is the answer for Android.

- [In-app Billing documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/index.html)
- [In-app Billing integration](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the photographs truly are photo quality, then try selling them on a stock photography site like [istockphoto.com](http://istockphoto.com).  You'll make more money.  I think that they also do video as well.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however, istockphoto.com only pays up to 40% of the profits.  People that know me are currently buying the pictures directly from me which has been my primary business.  I'm trying to use the android market and itunes app market specifically to try to reach new people.  People can already purchase photos directly from my website.  Also, my thought was to buy "medium" quality photos for their phones, and have the option of buying the photo / print quality photos directly from me.